# Why my styles of page are striked through in Firebug under HTML tab in styles sub section

Tags: html, css, firebug

I have an html page. When I inspect its elements with Firebug, its styles are striked-through. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser applies the style sheets as it goes through them.The first is applied and then the second etc.Thus if you have something like

```
div{color:#ffe000}
div{color:#ffffff}
```

The second style will be applied.

If you do not want any style to be overridden by a subsequent change you can use the !important attribute.This will prevent the style to be overridden which has this attribute .

```
div{color:#ffe000!important}
div{color:#ffffff}
```

Thus the div will retain its #ffe000 color .

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because that line of style is overridden by another style. It depends on the hierarchy of your stylesheets and where in your lines of code is the style at.

Example:

```
#test-element {
    display: block;
}

#test-element {
    display: none;
}
```

In your firebug you would see that the line "display:block" would have a strike-through as it is being overridden by the "display:none"

Comment: I mean I had my style poorly overridden with different properties.!!